# Object Loading Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am developing an application that consists of several different objects working together. Everything seems to work great, however, when I play this on a web server I notice the graphics and assets that are being loaded in from an external source are taking some time to load I'm not really sure what is going on I was hoping someone might provide some insight. Example, sometimes the graphic assets will not load at all, but audio seems to be loading in ok. Here is an example of my image loading class:

**GFXReg.as**

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class GFXReg extends Sprite {
        private var mc: MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        private var loader: Loader = new Loader();
        private var setW: Number;
        public var setH: Number;
        public var theH: Number;
        private var bool: Boolean = false;

        public function GFXReg(setSize: Boolean, W: Number, H: Number) {
            bool = setSize;
            if (bool) {
                setW = W;
                setH = H;
            }
        }

        private function loadData(e: Event) {
            if(loader.contentLoaderInfo.bytesLoaded == loader.contentLoaderInfo.bytesTotal){
                addChild(loader);   
                }else{
                        var text:TextField = new TextField();
                        text.text = "Loading..."
                        addChild(text);
                    }

            if (bool) {
                loader.width = setW;
                loader.height = setH;
            }
        }
        public function theData(file: String): void {
            loader.load(new URLRequest(file));
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadData);
        }
        public function getBytes(str:String):int{
            var num:int = 0;
                switch(str){
                        case "loaded":
                        num = loader.contentLoaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
                        break;
                        case "total":
                        num = loader.contentLoaderInfo.bytesTotal;
                        break;
                    }
                    return num;
            }
        public function removeData():void{
                loader.unloadAndStop(false);
                trace("unload?");
            }
        private function unloadData(e:Event):void{

            }
    }
}
```

**Main.as Sections**(This loads in all the appropriate sections when prompted):

```
public function Main() {
            xmlLoader = new XMLReg("config.xml", processXML);
        }
        private function processXML(e: Event): void {
            theXML = new XML(e.target.data);
            dir = theXML.MASTER.@DIRECTORY;
            //BACKGROUND
            bgGFX.theData(dir + theXML.MAINBG.@IMG);
            //INITIALIZE
            add(bgGFX,intro);

                              //INTRO WAS INSTANTIATED IN THE BEGINNING OF THIS CLASS
            intro.start();
                              /*start method adds objects to stage, to test as a solution*/

            addChildAt(header, numChildren);
            //...
```

Also in my **Main.as** class I have a private method transition which loads in the appropriate sections after the previous sections have been completed these assets usually take a few seconds to load in I've noticed when working on a web server.

```
        private function transition(e: Event): void {
//If intro is on the stage instantiate a new QuestionAnswer Object
            if (intro.stage) {
                header.enableMenu(true);
                qa = new QuestAnswer(feedBool,nameCounter,nameVar);
                qa.addEventListener("unload", transition);
                qa.addEventListener("addFeed", setFeedFalse);
                qa.addEventListener("addFeedTrue", setFeedTrue);
                qa.addEventListener("enableHelp",enableHelp);
                qa.addEventListener("getName",getName);
                addChildAt(qa, numChildren-1);
                remove(intro);
            } else if (qa.stage) {
//If QuestionAnswer is on the Stage instantiate a new Results Object
                header.enableMenu(true);
                header.enableHelp(false);
                results = new Results(qa.resultBundle());
                results.addEventListener("unload", transition);
                results.addEventListener("addFeed", setFeedFalse);
                results.addEventListener("addFeedTrue", setFeedTrue);
                results.addEventListener("setName",setName);
                addChildAt(results, numChildren-1);
                remove(qa);
            } else if (results.stage) {
//If Results is on the stage loop back and instantiate a new QuestionAnswer Object
                header.enableMenu(true);
                header.enableHelp(false);
                intro.enableAsset(true);
                qa = new QuestAnswer(feedBool,nameCounter,nameVar);
                qa.addEventListener("unload", transition);
                qa.addEventListener("addFeed", setFeedFalse);
                qa.addEventListener("addFeedTrue", setFeedTrue);
                addChildAt(qa, numChildren-1);
                trackAsset = true;
                remove(results);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are the graphics taking longer to load than you would expect given the size of the assets and the speed of your network connection?

Comment: Not necessarily, I've just really been having trouble making sure the assets are loaded and available before they are added to the stage.